# Error Message when Running npm init

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using **npm** for quite a while now, but this morning when I run **`npm init`** I get this error :

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-   cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

Somebody helps me!

Comment: There is an error of module does not load property

Comment: Please verify path

Comment: @Dipakchavda I have checked for ../lib/utils/unsupported.js and there's no utils directory in the ../lib directory. Do I need to reinstall nodejs ?

Comment: can you post full code

Comment: that's all the error trace I got. I have an empty directory and I run npm init inside that directory, and I get the error log that I have reported. Which full code are you referring to

Answer (score 0):

As the error error trace that is displayed is referencing a missing path (../lib/utils/unsupported.js), I simply decided to remove nodejs and npm altogether following the answer here 
[How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

After removing nodejs and npm I reinstall them using the node-v8.11.pkg installer.

It's npm init is now working fine.